# Alternative to price_inc_tax in expresso store 2

Tags: expresso-store, ee2

I need to show product prices including applicable tax in product form. I have tags like {price} {regular_price} but none of them can show price inclusive tax. I see that {price_inc_tax} was available in store 1 but deprecated in store 2. Is there any alternative available for it on store 2.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I had added prices inclusive tax in CP and checked checkbox in tax settings to indicate this. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not, because you are now expected to include the tax in your product price if you are using tax-inclusive pricing. From the [upgrade notes](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/store_20_upgrade_notes.html#tax_handling):

> In Store 2, prices are entered in the control panel exactly as you want them to be displayed. Taxes may be configured as "included in price", which indicates that the tax should not be added to the order total. For example, say you create a product which sells for $20.00, and a tax of 10% which is included in the price. In the checkout, when the customer purchases this item, they will see the item price as $20.00, a tax of $1.82, and an order total of $20.00.

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason (upgrading from EE1 to EE2 with all prices entered without tax), I wrote a [tax plugin](https://github.com/peteralewis/tax) which could display it however I wanted.

The documentation is non-existent, but this should get you going...

**Only**
Returns just the tax.

```
{exp:tax:only price="<price from store>"}
```

**Price**
Returns the total price (with tax)

```
{exp:tax:price price="<price from store>" included="no"}
```

**None**
Return the price without tax - assumes tax is included in price

```
{exp:tax:none price="<price from store>"}
```

Looks like it works as a tag pair too:

```
{exp:tax:only rate="5"}{price}{/exp:tax:only}
```

Additional parameters

- rate="5"
- show_currency="yes"
- currency="$"
- position="before" (currency symbol position, options: before, after)
- decimals="yes" (decimal places set through config only)
- thousands="yes" (show thousand separator - character set through config, defaults to ",")
- rounding="up" (valid options: up, down, nearest)
- included="no"

You can set any defaults in EE Config:

- tax_rate
- tax_included
- tax_currency
- tax_position
- tax_decimals
- tax_thousands
- tax_show_currency
- tax_rounding
- tax_decimal_places
- tax_thousand_symbol
- tax_decimal_symbol